# Problem with round() function in .Rmd exercise file

Tags: r-exams

I have a problem where I create a .Rmd file for an exercise and I include a large number together with the `round()` function. Here is a minimal example:

````
```{r data generation, echo = FALSE, results = "hide"}
Value = 12000.555
```

Question
========
temp

Meta-information
================
exname: temp
extype: num
exsolution: `r round(Value, 2)`
extol: 0.01
````

I try to compile this exercise into an exam using `exams2pdf()` yielding the following error:

```
exams2pdf("example.Rmd")
## Warning message: In read_metainfo(file) : NAs introduced by coercion
```

Why is that? I'm using R/exams version 2.3-6, and R version 3.6.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR: Use `fmt(Value, 2)` instead of `round(Value, 2)`. This avoids problems with scientific notation (and uses rounding away from zero). See `?fmt` for more details.

The reason for the error is actually not the `round()` function per se, but the fact the R by default uses scientific notation for numbers with a certain number of significant digits (factory-fresh default in R is `scipen = 7`). Furthermore, the `knitr` package (employed in the background by R/exams) tries to format this scientific notation nicely. So instead of `12000.56` the `knit()` function includes `1.200056 &times; 10<sup>4</sup>` in the Markdown file. You can see this when you run `xweave("example.Rmd")` and then inspect the resulting `example.md` file. And then the subsequent processing of the `exsolution` tag hence has problems to convert this back to a number, hence the warning.

To avoid this you could increase the `scipen` limit within the R code of the exercise, e.g., `options(scipen = 999)`. But this is very technical and tedious. This is one of the reasons why we have written the `fmt(...)` function that carries out various convenience tasks that have to do with formatting of numbers within R/exams exercises.