# Numeric exercises with large solution lead to error

Tags: r, r-exams

### Background

R/exams is a great tool for generating exams for students.

### Problem

When a numeric exercise has a large solution, an error is thrown:

```
Error in string2num(exsolution) : 
  all numeric items must be finite and non-missing
```

Is this a bug or am I missing something out?

### Minimal example

Here's a minimal exercise ("test-debug.Rmd") that provoked the error:

````
Question
========
Some text

Solution
========
Some solution

```{r}
sol <- 1e4
```

Meta-information
================
exname: test-debug
extype: num
exsolution: `r sol`
````

I used `exams2html` to render the exercise:

```
exams2html(file = "test-debug.Rmd",
           edir = path_to_exercise,
           dir = path_output)
```

### System info

exams 2.4-0

Comment: `exsolution: \`r fmt(sol, digits = 3)\`` may be worth trying, by comparison to one of their supplied examples:  https://www.r-exams.org/assets/posts/2017-08-14-currency8//currency8.Rmd

Comment: Hi Paul, I tried it and it solved the problem. I think you offered the solution. Thank you!

Comment: Great, I'll add it as an answer.

Comment: Additional background: The problem is that `knitr` switches to scientific notation in the `exsolution` which is not read correctly by R/exams. The following answer has some more details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61254298/problem-with-round-function-in-rmd-exercise-file/61258974#61258974

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
exsolution: `r fmt(sol, digits = 3)`
```

Based on a review of one of the supplied examples on their site: [r-exams.org/assets/posts/2017-08-14-currency8//currency8.Rmd](https://r-exams.org/assets/posts/2017-08-14-currency8//currency8.Rmd)

Comment: See also the answer to the following question which discusses the same problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61254298/problem-with-round-function-in-rmd-exercise-file/61258974#61258974