# Numeric questions with large tolerance throw error

Tags: r, r-exams

## Background

R/exams is a great tool for generating exams for students.

## Problem

When a numeric exercise has a large tolerance (`extol`), an error is thrown:

```
Error in if (!is.null(extol) && any(extol < 0)) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

Is this a bug or am I missing something out?

## Minimal example

Here's a minimal exercise  that provoked the error:

````
Question
========
Some text

Solution
========
Some solution

```{r}
sol <- 1e4
sol_tol <- 1e4
```

Meta-information
================
exname: test-debug
extype: num
exsolution: `r fmt(sol, 3)`
extol: `r sol_tol`
````

I used exams2html to render the exercise:

```
exams2html(file = "test-debug.Rmd",
           edir = "exercises",
           dir = "/.")
```

## System info

exams 2.4-0

Comment: `extol` contains `NA` values. This is not related to it being large. (I'm not familar with the exams package.)

Comment: I guess what happens: `knitr` switched to scientific notation and then the tolerance cannot be corrected to numeric. Adding `fmt()` should do the trick. Will check when I'm on a computer.

Comment: @AchimZeileis: Yes! `fmt()` did the trick. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Roland: In my case, no `NA`s in `sol_tol` or `extol`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure that both the `exsolution` and the `extol` actually contain numbers only. However, depending on the `scipen` option, large numbers might be converted to strings containing scientific notation.

In your example, you avoid the scientific notation by using the `fmt()` function in `exsolution`. But as you do not use `fmt()` in `extol`, this gets rendered into a string and not just a number.

The problem and corresponding solution are explained in a bit more detail in: [Problem with round() function in .Rmd exercise file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61254298/problem-with-round-function-in-rmd-exercise-file/61258974#61258974)

In short, either assure that `scipen` is sufficiently high or use a formatter like `fmt()` that assure to display it's input as a plain number only.